# Using importlib for cases like from x import *

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-importlib

How do I use `importlib` for dynamically reloading modules earlier imported as:

```
from my_module import *
import some_module as sm
```

The documentation gives example for plain imports like:

```
import my_module
```

as

```
importlib.reload('my_module')
```

version: Python 3.4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`from my_module import *` creates references to all names in `my_module` not starting with an underscore, or, if present, all names in the `my_module.__all__` sequence.

You'll have to re-create that same rebinding after a `importlib.reload()` call:

```
def reload_imported_names(module_name, globals, *names):
    """Reload module and rebind imported names.

    If no names are given, rebind all names exported by the module

    """
    importlib.reload(module_name)
    module = sys.modules[module_name]
    if not names:
        names = getattr(module, '__all__', 
                        (n for n in dir(module) if n[0] != '_'))
    for name in names:
        globals[name] = getattr(module, name)
```

where `globals` should be a reference to the globals of the module where you used `from module_name import *`. Within that module itself you can use the `globals()` function to access that dictionary.

The function support both the `from my_module import *` case, and the `from my_module import foo, bar` cases:

```
reload_imported_names('my_module', globals())  # import *
reload_imported_names('my_module', globals(), 'foo', 'bar')  # import foo, bar
```

Comment: Is there a way to handle aliased imports like `import some_module as sm`. Thanks

Comment: @tao: `import some_module as sm` is already handled by `importlib.reload()`. Just because you changed the name of the global binding to the module, doesn't change that it'll now point to a reloaded module.

Comment: @tao: in other words, `import some_module as sm` doesn't need any special handling.